# ActivePDF Toolkit in Windows Server 2003 x64

Tags: iis, windows-server-2003, 64-bit

I've recently migrated my app to a 64bit OS (from 32bit Win2k3) and am finding that one dependency - ActivePDF simply won't run under x64. I'm not sure if its by design, or just that it hasn't been tested for 64 bit operation.  Is there anyway to get this to run under 32bit mode somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked a lot with ActivePDF and have known them to be excellent with their support,  If you have a support contract I would try that.

I do not know specifically about 64bit.  We eventual traded in toolkit for iText because the were not supporting Acrobat 9 at the time.  64bit my have a similar fate.

Answer (score 0):

There was certainly a x64 bug in the ActivePDF toolkit. It ran fine on x64 hosts, as long as it was able to run in an 32bit threat - so you had to configure IIS to provide 32bit support.

The bug was recently fixed, the toolkit now provides native x64 support.